# Proper way to countdown and redirect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I'm using `ngRoute` module to handle multiple links in an angularJS single page application. Sometimes users reach wrong links an should be redirected (because content is dynamic, it depends on external source, but it's not relevant).

Let's say I want to redirect user after 10 seconds, meanwhile I want to display a warning and show the countdown. I just use a `seconds` variable starting form 10 and a function with `$interval` lower number of seconds until 0, then redirect

```
$scope.seconds = 10;
$scope.startCountdown = function () {
    var intervalPromise = $interval(function () {
        if ($scope.seconds > 0) {
            $scope.seconds--;
        }
        else {
            $interval.cancel(intervalPromise);
            $location.search({});
            $location.path("/");
        }
    }, 1000);
}
$scope.startCountdown();
```

It works but when the user change location before the countdown finish (he can call a `$location.path("/Summary")` from top menu) the countdown still goes on in background and after a few seconds he is redirected to home.

How can I solve this? I could use `$scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function (args) { ... }` event to cancel promise but that way I need to save the `intervalPromise` variable and... it seem just too wired! Is there a better way to implement this countdown logic in a straightforward way?

Answer (score 2):

First use `$timeout` not `$interval` for this

And why storing the promise seems to be too wired ? Of course you need to store it somewhere in order to call it later : here is how i would do  it :

```
var promise = $timeout(function(){
    // your code
    promise = null; 
    //perform redirect
}, 10000);
$scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function (args) {
    if(promise != null){
       $timeout.cancel(promise);
     } 
};
```